# Proof of union of a set and its complement is equivalent to a universe

Tags: proof-verification, elementary-set-theory

**THEOREM**

Let U be the universe, and let A be a subset of U. Then

$$ A \cup A^c = U $$

**PROOF**

Let x be any object. We must show that

$$ x \in ( A \cup A^c ) \iff x \in U $$

From the definition of complement we know that, $ A^c = U - A $. Thus

$$  [x \in A \lor x\in(U-A)] \iff x \in U $$ 
$$ [x \in A \lor ( x\in U \land x\notin A)]=\iff x \in U  $$
$$  [(x \in A \lor x \in U) \land ( x \in A \lor x \notin A)] \iff x \in U $$
$$  [(x \in A \lor x \in U) \land (x \in A \implies x \in A)] \iff x \in U $$

Now I use earlier proved statement $ A \cup B = B$ iff $A \subset B$ and other basic definitions, so I deduce the next thing

$$ U \cap A = U $$

But A is subset and I know that $ B \cap A = A$ iff $ A\subset B$, that was proved earlier as well. So at last I've got that $ U \cap A = A $, and it's not what I wanted. Where is the mistake?

Comment: People proving set identities for the first time are always tempted to write long strings of equations where each step is a manipulation of symbols, when in fact it's much easier (and much clearer) to give a direct proof by double containment—that is, prove $A \cup A^c \subseteq U$ and $U \subseteq A \cup A^c$ separately, working directly with the definitions of the sets involved. I suspect the reason why you've made a mistake (regardless of what the mistake *is*) is that you're treating this as an algebraic problem, when that's not really what it is.

Comment: How is $A^c$ defined in this context?

Comment: Ok I've got it, thanks.

Comment: Also, please remove that inappropriate name

Answer (score 4):

Let $A\subseteq U$.

Then for *every* element $x$ of $U$ *exactly one* of the following statements is true:

- $x$ is an element of $A$.
- $x$ is not an element of $A$.

*By definition* $A^{\complement}$ is the subset of $U$ that contains *exactly all elements* of $U$ that are not elements of $A$.

So we could also state that for *every* $x\in U$ *exactly one* of the following statements is true:

- $x\in A$
- $x\in A^{\complement}$

This together comes to the same as: $A\cup A^{\complement}=U$ and $A\cap A^{\complement}=\varnothing$.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sure your proof is fine but this follows almost by definition.

Definition $A^c = \{x\in U| x\not \in A\}$ and $A$ tautologically is  $\{x \in U| x \in A\}$.

So $A\cup A^c = \{x\in U| x\in  A$ or $x \not \in A\}= \{x \in U\} = U$.

Answer (score 0):

Recall that $A\subset U$ and $A^c=U\setminus A=\{x\in U:x\notin A\}\subset U$ and so $A\cup A^c\subset U$. Again for $x\in U$ if $x\in A$ then $x\in A\cup A^c$ else if $x\in A^c$ then $x\in A\cup A^c$. So as a whole $U\subset A\cup A^c$.

Answer (score 0):

You are overcomplicating things. We can begin by proving $U \subseteq A \cup A^C$:

Let $x \in U$. If $x \in A$, we are done! Otherwise, $x \in A^c$, so we are also done.

The other inclusion is trivial